# how to dynamically add nested view inside inflated view

Tags: android, android-layout

In my view I want to add imageview in tablerow view which in inflated by list view, so I can add imageview dynamically in list view but I can not add in a table row dynamically. Please help me with this issue.

This is the class file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView imagegrid = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    imagegrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Activity mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Activity mainActivity) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mContext = mainActivity;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View customRow = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) customRow.findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        /* Create a new row to be added. */

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(mContext);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        /*
         * Create view to add view to row, here i am adding only button you
         * can andd any view you want
         */
        Button b = new Button(mContext);
        b.setText("Dynamic Button");
        b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        /* Add Button to row. */
        tr.addView(b);

        /* Add row to TableLayout. */
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return customRow;
    }
}
```

this is my xml file....

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: i did ....tr.addview(lblid);..it's not working ...any other solution is there..

Answer (score 0):

you need to go through following steps

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourtbllayout);
/* Create a new row to be added. */

TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

/*Create view to add view to row, here i am adding only button you can andd any view you want*/
                Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setText("Dynamic Button");
            b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            /* Add Button to row. */
            tr.addView(b);


/* Add row to TableLayout. */
tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: not working...dude...instead of creating view dynamically if i create view inside table row then it is working....but i need to create dynamic ..

Comment: i updated quesation...and there is just blank screen is coming...button is not display

Comment: try replacing wrap_content with fill_parent or match_parent also set it to your tablelayout.xml